# QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor calls deprecated api(fetchCount)

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I know that `fetchCount` has been deprecated since `queryDsl 5.0` however,`spring-data-jpa 3.1` still uses fetchCount.

`AbstractJPAQuery.java` :

```java
    ...
    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public long fetchCount() {
        try {
            if (getMetadata().getGroupBy().size() > 1 || getMetadata().getHaving() != null) {
                logger.warning("Fetchable#fetchCount() was computed in memory! See the Javadoc for AbstractJPAQuery#fetchCount for more details.");
                Query query = createQuery(null, false);
                return query.getResultList().size();
            }

            Query query = createQuery(null, true);
            return (Long) query.getSingleResult();
        } finally {
            reset();
        }
    }
    ....
```

`QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor.java` :

```java
    ...
    @Override
    public long count(Predicate predicate) {
        return createQuery(predicate).fetchCount();
    }
    ...
```

I wonder if spring-data-jpa project is still using fetchCount. Thanks for reading.